# Reset and setFieldValue with react-seelect within Formik

Tags: reactjs, formik, react-select

I have a Formik form which uses check-boxes and selects. For the select field I am using react-select. There is no problem to submit the form but when I want to reset the form the react-select part is not clearing and also when I want to prefill the form after a push of a button with setFieldValue, again the react-select part is not responding.

How can I make it work this form with react-select within Formik?

https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-breeze-dyhi3b

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import FormikReactSelect from "./components/FormikReactSelect";

function App() {
  return <FormikReactSelect />
}

export default App;
```

FormikReactSelect.js

```
import React, {useRef} from "react";
import {Form, Field, Formik, FieldArray} from "formik";

import SelectField from "./SelectField";

function FormikReactSelect() {
  const formikRef = useRef();

  const drinkDist = ["Wine", "Beer", "Whiskey"];

  const countryDist = ["US", "FR", "DE", "BE", "IT"];

  const arrToValLab = (arr) => {
    if (arr !== undefined) {
      const valLab = arr.map((t) => ({
        value: t,
        label: t,
      }));
      return valLab;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  };

  const onClick = () => {
    if (formikRef.current) {
      formikRef.current.setFieldValue("drinks", ["Whiskey"]);
    }
    if (formikRef.current) {
      formikRef.current.setFieldValue("countries", ["FR"]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Formik
        innerRef={formikRef}
        enableReinitialize={true}
        initialValues={{drinks: [], countries: []}}
      >
        {({
          values,
          handleChange,
          handleSubmit,
          handleBlur,
          resetForm,
          setFieldValue,
        }) => (
          <Form noValidate>
            Drinks:
            <FieldArray
              name="drinks"
              render={(arrayHelpers) => (
                <div>
                  {drinkDist.map((r, i) => (
                    <div key={i}>
                      <label>
                        <Field
                          name="drinks"
                          type="checkbox"
                          value={r}
                          checked={values.drinks.includes(r)}
                          onChange={(e) => {
                            if (e.target.checked) {
                              arrayHelpers.push(r);
                            } else {
                              const idx = values.drinks.indexOf(r);
                              arrayHelpers.remove(idx);
                            }
                          }}
                        />
                        {" " + r}
                      </label>
                    </div>
                  ))}
                </div>
              )}
            />
            Countries:
            <Field
              component={SelectField}
              name="countries"
              options={arrToValLab(countryDist)}
            />
            <button
              type="button"
              onClick={() => {
                resetForm();
              }}
            >
              Reset
            </button>
            {JSON.stringify(values, null, 2)}
          </Form>
        )}
      </Formik>
      Sending preset values:
      <button onClick={onClick}>Set Field</button>
    </>
  );
}

export default FormikReactSelect;
```

SelectFireld.js

```
import React from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

import {useField} from "formik";

export default function SelectField(props) {
  const [field, state, {setValue, setTouched}] = useField(props.field.name); // eslint-disable-line

  const onChange = (value) => {
    let arrValue = [];
    value.map((k) => arrValue.push(k.value));
    setValue(arrValue);
  };

  return <Select {...props} isMulti onChange={onChange} onBlur={setTouched} />;
}
```

Comment: I solved this by adding `value={values[selectName] || ''}` (values from Formik) - I don't want to post as an answer as I haven't fully tested it yet but initially it works as planned

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved my day. For this case I added value={arrToValLab(values["countries"])} and it works :)